# How to multiply individual elements of a list with a number?

Tags: python, numpy, multiplication

```
S = [22, 33, 45.6, 21.6, 51.8]
P = 2.45
```

Here `S` is an array

How will I multiply this and get the value?

```
SP = [53.9, 80.85, 111.72, 52.92, 126.91]
```

Comment: In Python S is not an array, it is a list. There is a very big difference betweeb the two types of containers. If you want numerical arrays, use numpy.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use built-in [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) function:

```
result = map(lambda x: x * P, S)
```

or [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that is a bit more pythonic:

```
result = [x * P for x in S]
```

Comment: Just as a note, operations on arrays, like scalar multiplication are highly optimized in numpy, and are significantly faster than list comprehensions. It is generally advisable to not treat numpy arrays like python lists.

Comment: "*It is generally advisable to not treat numpy arrays like python lists*", what does that mean in general? and how is it related  to the current answer which doesn't use NumPy? Is this answer still true in 2021 (probably but still not sure, maybe some new operator has appeared to indicate we really want the distributive operation and not the list replication)?

Answer (score 77):

In NumPy it is quite simple

```
import numpy as np
P=2.45
S=[22, 33, 45.6, 21.6, 51.8]
SP = P*np.array(S)
```

I recommend taking a look at the NumPy tutorial for an explanation of the full capabilities of NumPy's arrays:

https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial

Answer (score 21):

If you use `numpy.multiply`

```
S = [22, 33, 45.6, 21.6, 51.8]
P = 2.45
multiply(S, P)
```

It gives you as a result

```
array([53.9 , 80.85, 111.72, 52.92, 126.91])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [functional](https://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html) approach using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html#built-in-functions), [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) and [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.mul):

```
import operator
from itertools import repeat


def scalar_multiplication(vector, scalar):
    yield from map(operator.mul, vector, repeat(scalar))
```

Example of usage:

```
>>> v = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> c = 3
>>> list(scalar_multiplication(v, c))
[3, 6, 9, 12]
```