# Multiplying array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194959/in-python-how-will-you-multiply-individual-elements-of-an-array-with-a-floating) question I see how to multiply a whole numpy array with the same number (second answer, by JoshAdel). But when I change P into the maximum of a (long) array, is it better to store the maximum on beforehand, or does it calculate the maximum of H just once in the second example?

```
import numpy as np
H = [12,12,5,32,6,0.5]
P=H.max()
S=[22, 33, 45.6, 21.6, 51.8]
SP = P*np.array(S)
```

or

```
import numpy as np
H = [12,12,5,32,6,0.5]
S=[22, 33, 45.6, 21.6, 51.8]
SP = H.max()*np.array(S)
```

So does it calculate `H.max()` for every item it has to multiply, or is it smart enough to it just once? In my code `S` and `H` are longer arrays then in the example.

Comment: You can make up an example consisting from like 10^6 vectors and check. Or run it in a loop. There is even a [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module for this.

Comment: The first code snippet is 4.47us versus 11.9us but I would profile it using your real data

Comment: Actually there appears to be no difference in the timings, for a random array of 100,000 elements it takes 51.2us just to calculate `P=H.max()` then 165 us for `SP = P*np.array(S)` and then 217us for `SP = H.max()*np.array(S)` so there is little difference

Comment: @EdChum okay. I have been trying with timeit myself, but I never done it before, so I couldnt get it tested as fast as you did it. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is little difference between the 2 methods:

```
In [74]:

import numpy as np
H = np.random.random(100000)
%timeit P=H.max()
S=np.random.random(100000)
%timeit SP = P*np.array(S)
%timeit SP = H.max()*np.array(S)
10000 loops, best of 3: 51.2 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 165 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 217 µs per loop
```

Here you can see that the individual step of pre-calculating `H.max()` is no different from calculating it in a single line