# How to merge two plots on the same graph?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two graphs: one is the list of each day in 2018 (datetime object) on x-axis with its corresponding value on y-axis, the other one is the list of each week in 2018( 52 in total) on x-axis with its corresponding average value on y-axis.

I was asked to merge two plots on the same graph. However, if I set both domains to be days in 2018, the latter graph goes wrong and following shows up

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (365,) and (52,)
```

What should I do to get the things sorted out? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690480/matplotlib-valueerror-x-and-y-must-have-same-first-dimension

Comment: I have tried that and the same error shows up

Comment: Can you provide your code and some example data? Accroding to your description, maybe the x-data of your latter graph is coverted to shape of (365,) whereas the y-data maintains the shape of (52,).

Comment: That is exactly where the problem lies. But I just need to plot it with these data.