# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (165,) and (166,)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, librosa

I'm looping through a list of audio filenames, loading them, calculating the STE and RMSE, and then plotting said values. However, the occasional error message is thrown for about 20% of the files.

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (165,) and (166,)
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (240,) and (241,)
```

So on and so forth.

I took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63594625/why-do-i-keep-on-getting-x-and-y-must-have-same-first-dimension-but-have-shape) and I believe the problem may be similar as I am also using square brackets in my call to `plt.plot` on line 2 of the code below. However, changing this to parentheses throws a syntax error. I also find it strange that only 20% of >1000 samples are affected and that the shape seems to be incremented by 1.

Is this a metadata issue? What exactly could be causing this problem?

```
frames = range(len(energy))
t = librosa.frames_to_time(frames, sr=SAMPLE_RATE, hop_length=HOP_LENGTH)

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.plot(t[:len(rmse)], rmse_max_scaled, color='b')
plt.plot(t, energy_max_scaled, 'r--')
librosa.display.waveplot(sample, sr=SAMPLE_RATE, alpha=0.4)
plt.legend(('RMSE', 'Energy'))
```

Comment: @JohanC I've edited my question with the definition of `t` value which is times calculated from frames. I'm not sure what you mean by one-to-one correspondence. I tried your suggestion but the errors persist. Also using `plt.plot(t, rmse_max_scaled, color='b')` and `plt.plot(t, energy_max_scaled, 'r--')` achieves the same graphs on the samples that work but 20% still throw the above error.

Comment: Your problem is that there are not enough `t` values.  You need as many `t` values as corresponding `y` values.  So e.g. `frames = range(len(rmse))` for the first plot.  And `frames = range(len(energy_max_scaled))` for the second plot.  It is a bit suspicious that `rmse_max_scaled` and `energy_max_scaled` don't have the same length.

Comment: @JohanC thank you for clearing things up. I was able to code a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue as pointed out by @JohanC is that there were not enough `t` values as the corresponding `y` values. Reformatting the code as follows solved the problem.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))

frames = range(len(rmse))
t = librosa.frames_to_time(frames, sr=SAMPLE_RATE, hop_length=HOP_LENGTH)
plt.plot(t[:len(rmse)], rmse_max_scaled, color='b')

frames = range(len(energy))
t = librosa.frames_to_time(frames, sr=SAMPLE_RATE, hop_length=HOP_LENGTH)
plt.plot(t[:len(energy)], energy_max_scaled, 'r--')

librosa.display.waveplot(sample, sr=SAMPLE_RATE, alpha=0.4)
plt.legend(('RMSE', 'Energy'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because x and y are the same length and there are not enough values of t.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).