# x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (2,) and (1,)

Tags: python

I have had to write a function that reads in a csv file of this format and returns a list of tuples containing each pair of abilities which I have done successfully. I am now trying to write a function which takes a list of the format returned by my answer to his as an argument, and uses matplotlib to produce a plot showing the probability that player a beats player b against ra/rb for each pair.

When I trying to show my graph I get the error: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (2,) and (1,). I have tried changing results into a string but the line for the graph does not show.

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def csvAbilites():
    with open('abilites.csv') as csv_file:
        next(csv_file)
        data=[tuple(map(int,line)) for line in csv.reader(csv_file)]
        return(data)


for results in (csvAbilites()): #play abilites
    ra = results[0] / (results[0] + results[1]) #probability a wins
    plt.plot((results), (ra))

plt.xlabel('Ability of Player A / Ability of Player B')
plt.ylabel('Probabilty A wins')
plt.title('Probabilty of A Winning for different player abilites')
plt.show()
```

Comment: `ra` is a single value; `results` is a sequence.  How would expect that to appear as a plot?

Comment: I [googled the exact title](https://www.google.com/search?q=x+and+y+must+have+same+first+dimension%2C+but+have+shapes+(2%2C)+and+(1%2C)), I suggest to start from there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690480/matplotlib-valueerror-x-and-y-must-have-same-first-dimension)