# Python - multiple list by a scalar

Tags: python, numpy

Refer to the question mentioned on this link [In Python how will you multiply individual elements of a list with a floating point or integer number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194959/in-python-how-will-you-multiply-individual-elements-of-an-array-with-a-floating)

I use `import numpy as np`; then multiply a list with a flaoting number and stored the updated values in the same list. However, the new values are like [[array([ 10.])] .....

Now I want to remove array and use the list with the integer value.

Comment: Please show some code, input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to turn the `np.array()` back to a list?

```
import numpy as np
P=2.45
S=[22, 33, 45.6, 21.6, 51.8]
SP = P*np.array(S)
SP_LIST =list(SP)
```

As the post you link to also contains:

```
[x * P for x in S]
```

returns a list directly