# Updating values in numpy array doesn't work with for loops on list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Suppose a 2d numpy array as the following:

`A = np.ones((5,5))`

Now, I want to update (change) all the values of A using the following code:

`for row in A:
    for entry in row:
         entry = 999`

After this, the entries en A are 1, i.e. the matrix is the same as the original.

But, If I run this code, the values are changed:

`for i,row in enumerate(A):
    for j,entry in enumerate(row):
         A[i][j] = 999`

Why this is happening?

Is the `cell` variable a copy and not a pointer?

Comment: A concurrent question with the same issue, but for a list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355739/multiply-every-element-of-a-list-by-a-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because when you reassign `entry`, you are simply redefining a variable.  When you first define `entry`, you are assigning to it a *value*, not a position in the array.

Comment: Thank you! I was very confused because I was thinking on how python points to references and not values.