# How to multiply a vector by a scalar in python?

Tags: python

I want to multiply a vector by a scalar by a cicle, i.e:
`x1=[2,3,4,5]` and i want to multiply it by 2, so that i get, `x1=2(x2)`, `x2=[4,6,8,10]`.
I tried doing this:

```py
def multiplicar_vector(x1):
    x2=[]
    for i in x1:
        x2[i] = (x1[i])*2
    print(x2)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiply every element of a list by a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355739/multiply-every-element-of-a-list-by-a-number)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use pure python, you would likely use a list comprehension.

```py
x1 = [item * 2 for item in x2]
```

This is taking each item in the x2, and multiplying it by 2. The square brackets indicate that you want to make a list of the results. It's equivalent to:

```py
x1 = []
for item in x2:
    x1.append(item * 2)
```

Really though, most people would use numpy when dealing with lots of vectors as it much faster and easier.

```py
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
x2 = 2 * x1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each item and multiply it

```
x1=[2,3,4,5]
N=2
x2 = [ x * N for x in x1]
print(x2)
```

Incase you want to use a predefined package. Convert your list vector type into a numpy vector array type and multiply.

```
import numpy as np
x1=[2,3,4,5]
N=2
my_array = np.array(x1)
x2 = my_array * N
print(x2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a python package that does this really well : numpy

```
import numpy as np

x2  = np.array(x1)*2
```

Comment: thak you very much