# Mathematic Operational an integer to a bunch of value or list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

is there other way to do an matematic operational ( add, substract, multiply divided ) from an integer foreach value inside a list ?

for example:

```
a = 4
arr = list(20,1,5,36,10,31,100)
```

the `a` variable need to substract/multiply/divided to all values inside those list using `for` function like below snippet.

```
ar = []
for x in arr
    a = 4*x
    ar.append(a)
```

Is there any a better approach to solve this rather than using for/while loop ?

Comment: take a look at `numpy` which supports vectorization on arrays.

Comment: Use `numpy` arrays which can be found https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/quickstart.html . you can simply do `a = 4*np.array(arr)`

Comment: In case you cannot use numpy: `ar = [4*xi for xi in arr]`

Comment: More ways [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194959/how-to-multiply-individual-elements-of-a-list-with-a-number)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your for loop

Answer (score 1):

Numpy or other vectorization methods notwithstanding, you're looking for list comprehensions.

```
arr = list(20,1,5,36,10,31,100)
quadrupled_arr = [x * 4 for x in arr]
```